# How do you display a specific phrase your looking for from a string in POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Here is the sample row value

```
CREATION_DATE: 2021-08-30
USER_EMAIL: 'jack@sample.com
ACTION: 'FileAccessedExtended'
AUDITDATA: 
{
   "OrganizationId":"orgid1231231",
   "RecordType":6,
   "UserKey":"i:0h.f|membership|10032000de9e9feb@live.com",
   "UserType":0,
   "Version":1,
   "Workload":"SharePoint",
   "ClientIP":"11.11.11.11",
   "ObjectId":"https:\/\/someorganization.sharepoint.com\/sites\/MondayMeetings862\/Shared Documents\/folder\/folders\/somefolder\/Contact Database\/Investment Contact Database (MASTER) 1.xlsx",
   "UserId":"jack@sample.com",
   "CorrelationId":"12-031-23809123809172309",
   "EventSource":"SharePoint",
   "ItemType":"File",
   "ListId":"334b5378-2a4c-4ba6-b1ac-1ccb51a38687",
   "ListItemUniqueId":"a46a8f64-0ecf-415b-b372-32852c160d74",
   "Site":"2839182391823819238192389",
   "UserAgent":"MSOCS",
   "WebId":"1092301723729813",
   "HighPriorityMediaProcessing":false,
   "SourceFileExtension":"xlsx",
   "SiteUrl":"https:\/\/someorganization.sharepoint.com\/sites\/MondayMeetings862\/",
   "SourceFileName":"Investment Contact Database (MASTER) 1.xlsx",
   "SourceRelativeUrl":"Shared Documents\/folder\/folders\/COMMERCIAL\/Contact Database"
}
```

Desired output:

```
CREATION_DATE: 2021-08-30  
USER_EMAIL: Jack@sample.com          
ACTION: File Access Extended                
CLIENTIP: 11.11.11.11
```

Comment: Looks like json to me.

Comment: Goodness omg.. -__- more work.

Comment: What data type is the column `auditdata`?

Comment: @ThomasWard: Postgres has a [lot of functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to work with JSON values

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `auditdata` is a column of type `jsonb` (or at least `json`) you can use the [`->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to extract a value from it:

```
select creation_date, user_email, action,
       auditdata ->> 'ClientIP' as client_ip
from the_table;
```

If for some reason, the column is defined properly as a `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  you need to cast the value `auditdata::jsonb ->> 'ClientIP'`

Comment: Thank you so much this thing worked like a charm, just had to convert the data type to json... works like magic

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here come a bunch of if's. If AuditData is an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). And if ClientIP is reliably in the same position, then

```
SELECT AuditData[6] FROM MyTable
```

should give

```
"ClientIP":"11.11.11.11"
```

You can remove the double quotes by using the [string function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) replace to replace double quote with nothing.